# Generar archivo ".sql" desde CODEIGNITER

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Que tal, alguien que me pueda ayudar a generar un archivo ".sql"  un backup de mi base de datos desde php utilizando codeigniter, que solo sean unas tablas las cuales se encuentran en un arreglo

$tables = array(
                "tabla1", "tabla2", "tabla3");

y que ese archivo se guarde en una carpeta del proyecto ejemplo

```
http://127.0.0.1/nomProyecto/index.php/assets/backups/archivo.sql
```

Comment: Que has intentado?

Comment: estoy en blanco amigo, no se por donde comenzar :/